# Connecting a 200 amp sub panel to 600 amp line

Tags: electrical-panel

I have 600 amps feeding a 600 amp main panel.
It is a GE panel, 600 amp rated bottom feed and the sub panel is less then 1 foot away.

Can i feed a 200 amp sub panel with main breaker with 4/0 wire and bond it directly to the feeders on the main panel ?[image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the main panel please, including any labeling on the inside of the panel's door? Also, how far away will this subpanel be from the main panel?

Comment: What is the tap distance I want to provide the correct code reference in 240.21 . What is this load going to? It makes a difference if the 83% rule can be used. What code version is in use or what state are you in? We would need this info to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: The panel is a ge panel 400 amp rated bottom feed and the sub panel is less then 1 foot away

Comment: @Elias -- can you please post photos of the labeling on the inside of said 400A panel's door please?

Comment: There are important specs on the panel labeling that are needed before we can comment.  That's why ThreePhaseEel is asking for a picture.  If you don't provide that then we really cannot comment.

Comment: @Elias -- can you also get us a photo of said panel (door open, cover on)?